# Why was this SO question voted down?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting, down-votes

I am quite new to StackOverflow and I am trying to understand how this site works, it´s rules and to "fit in" as best as possible.

I recently posted this question:

[Equivalent of include() in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928331/equivalent-of-include-in-html)

It was voted up and down, twice each.

I went to the FAQ of downvoting and I quote:

"Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."

As down voting is a "hard" earned privilege I want to understand why this question was considered no helpful or not programming related.

I just want to understand and improve the quality of my questions!

Comment: Which FAQ of downvoting? I don't remember ever seeing one that says it's for "extreme cases." This community does tend to have a too-many-FAQs problem.

Comment: Not FAQ sorry: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explain what you are doing in your question, not only what you need. This will prevent you having to post comments to answers such as:

- I am very limited, I am actually asking for fmbl tab pages in facebook.
- No, I cant use iframes. thanks

This will prevent people who want to help from wasting their time writing answers that you can't use, and will most likely help you get a useful answer sooner.

Comment: I agree and got your answer as the correct one but i thinks the question should have been read more thoroughly by some (except for the iframe that I totally missed)

Comment: @Trufa: In other words, [describe the problem, not your attempted solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/54262).

Answer (score 0):

1. Spelling
2. Unclarity. Did you mean 'just in a browser' or on the server side?

Note: I didn't vote on this at all, so I'm just guessing.

It's a very short question and easily could lead to someone downvoting because you didn't take the time to fully explain what you were on about.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! As for spelling I think it wasn´t THAT bad english is no my language and sometimes I can miss catching some of them! sorry